# Rails 4 App image assets pointing to wrong CloudFront domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

I'm running a Rails 4 app on Heroku, using CloudFront as the CDN for some image assets. I have a Production app and a Staging app. On CloudFront, I have separate distributions for Production and Staging. I'm precompiling assets locally and pushing them to Heroku.

My production.rb has the following:

```
# production.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'xxxx.cloudfront.net'
# Use special staging CDN if pushing to staging
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'yyyy.cloudfront.net' if ENV['PUSH_TO'] && ENV['PUSH_TO'].downcase == 'staging'
```

So I'm specifying a different asset_host depending on if I'm pushing to staging or production.

However, when I push to staging, the resulting images are missing and pointing to the Production CloudFront distribution.

I put some logging statements in the app to ensure that `config.action_controller.asset_host` is set to the correct Staging distribution.

If I manually access the image urls by changing the host from the Production host to the Staging host they work, so I know the fingerprints updated correctly.

My .css.scss.erb file contains:

`.importance1 { background-image: image-url("<%= asset_path 'myImage1.png' %>"); }`

I made sure to clear my `public/assets` and `tmp` folders.

So what could be causing my assets on Staging to be pointing to the wrong CloudFront distribution?

**Update:** I've discovered that only the assets that are referred to with `asset_path` from other assets (css files) are getting the wrong CDN host. Meanwhile, assets that are displayed from views using `image_tag` are working fine. This makes me think that the problem is during precompiling assets, the wrong url's are getting output from `asset_path` in the css files. Not sure why though. I'm calling `rake RAILS_ENV=production assets:clean assets:precompile` and like I've said, I tried modifying production.rb to explicitly use the staging CDN only as a test and it still didn't use it (the assets still point to the Production CDN.)

Comment: Just as a sanity check, have you tried using an if/else?

Comment: I took the sanity check even further and replaced the settings with just `config.action_controller.asset_host = 'yyyy.cloudfront.net'` and still my images are pointing to 'xxxx.cloudfront.net'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out my problem.. Even though my staging app was using the correct asset_host, and the files were being served from the correct CDN, the urls within those files were pointing to the wrong CDN (the production CDN.) This was because while precompiling assets, the PUSH_TO env variable wasn't set, so the logic in my production.rb was using the production CDN. The solution was to do:

`rake RAILS_ENV=production PUSH_TO=staging assets:clean assets:precompile`

The key was the PUSH_TO=staging in there. This fixed all my problems!

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that your conditional on this line is returning false:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'yyyy.cloudfront.net' if ENV['PUSH_TO'] && ENV['PUSH_TO'].downcase == 'staging'
```

Either that or the asset_host won't allow being set twice. Don't know why that would be. Might be better to put that in an else block.

So fix that and you'll be set.

BUT....

Isn't this what environment files are for? Why don't you have this in your environments/staging.rb file? If it doesn't work there, you've fugged up your environment configuration and kinda defeated the whole purpose of multiple environments...

Comment: Like I said, I put logging statements in to check the value of `config.action_controller.asset_host` and it is correctly set to the staging host. I connected to the rails console and checked the value as well. I even completely replaced those config settings and just left `config.action_controller.asset_host = 'yyyy.cloudfront.net'` and still the images were pointing to `xxxx.cloudfront.net`.